# Unexpected error from external database driver

Tags: .net, export-to-excel

While uploading Excel files to DB server some files cannot be uploaded. This error was caused while getting the column names of that excel file using the function:

```
dtExcel = objConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Columns, Nothing)
```

Comment: What error you are getting? Provide more details.

Comment: objconn="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FileUploadV2\FlatFile\FOD_Feb2011_31jan11_Upd_001_1-4.xlsx;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"  this is the connection string im using. and dtexcel is the datatable. im binding the column names of that excelfile to a datatable. while binding im getting this error 'Unexpected error from external database driver (1).'

Comment: On which OS. Win 7 / XP / Server ?

Comment: Windows 7 os. only some excel files throwing the error

Answer (score 1):

Seems like problem with Excel OLEDB driver and/or connection string

Try these posts

1. [Diagnosing an OLEDB exception when Quering Excel 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461053/diagnosing-an-oledb-exception-when-quering-excel-2010)
2. http://connectionstrings.com/excel-2007

Comment: hey if ter is the problem in connection string as you said i cannot upload other excel 2010 files too. but while uploading some files only im getting this error.... thanks

Comment: Excel 2007 or Excel 2010 Files?

Comment: got the solution i have included imex=1 in the connection string. before i didnt include this so it treats as the excel data. when i put this code it treats all the data as text and shows the columnname.

Comment: I encountered this issue after a colleague of mine decided to install Excel on the server. This action seemed to update or replace Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable drivers we used before. Adding IMEX=1 fixed the problem. Also, if before I had to compile my Windows service for Any CPU to use the drivers on 64-bit server, with Excel installed, I have to compile for x86 to make everything work.